# OneDrive access SharePoint library when connected to internet only

Tags: onedrive-for-business, sharepoint-library

My company has a lot of documents on a network share we can access locally and through a VPN when outside.

I plan to move the files to our Office 365 Sharepoint Library and access them only when connected to internet. I don't want to sync the files on each computer.

Is there a way to do that with the new OneDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OneDrive will pull down local copies of the files, so that isn't the right approach. You'd be looking for a mapped network drive instead, but these don't work very well in SharePoint Online. Credentials expire and users get all sorts of access denied errors forcing them to sign out completely and sign back in.

Comment: I knew this solution but hoped there was a cross platform and reliable way to share files with Office 365. I need to find a cloud solution to do this now... Thanks

Comment: The simple answer would be just move them all off of the network share and access them in SharePoint Online, they would still be available on the network (via the browser) and via the internet (without VPN).

Comment: Actually I want to keep everything from a native tool like explorer or finder